# Cambiar el idioma del menú "Help" de R studio al español en windows

Tags: r, rstudio

estoy utilizando R studio y me gustaría saber como puedo poner el idioma en español en la parte de help, para que cuando ponga un comando como `?getwd` me salga la información de esta ventana en español:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si alguien sabe como puedo poner esto en español (estoy usando un Windows 10) se lo agradecería bastante, muchas gracias.

Comment: Habiendo quitado las etiquetas no relacionadas: [parece](https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/issues/4388) que RStudio sigue estando sólo en inglés.

Comment: entonces no hay alguna manera de cambiarlo al español?

Comment: Se puede [cambiar el locale](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16347731/how-to-change-the-locale-of-r) para los mensajes de salida y errores. No he encontrado nada más; esperar a ver si alguien más sabe algo diferente

Comment: perfecto, y muchas gracias

Answer (score 1):

Rstudio no cuenta con una traducción al español de 'Help'.

Puedes redirigir la ayuda hacia tu navegador predeterminado y usar algún plugin para traducir la webpage (i.e. Chrome cuenta con traducción automática).

Para ello debes comentar las líneas 23 al 26 de `Options.R` ubicado en `C:\Program Files\RStudio\R`:

```r
# .rs.setOption("browser", function(url)
# {
#    .Call("rs_browseURL", url, PACKAGE = "(embedding)")
# })
```

Reinicia RStudio y ahora cada vez que llames a la ayuda con `help` o `?`, la ayuda se abrirá en el navegador.

Comment: respecto a la respuesta sobre la traducción de la "ayuda" en R. ¿Podrías ser más detallado en los pasos a seguir? Gracias